# Creating group item in top bar menu

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make DB selection in top bar menu in my winform application. I found how to place checked state in design time, but I can't uncheck it in run time.

[image]

My task is even more complicated. I need to `Original` and `Test` act as group. When first one is checked, second one is unchecked and vice versa. I'm planning to achieve this with `CheckedChanged` events:

```
    private void testToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        originalToolStripMenuItem.Checked = !testToolStripMenuItem.Checked ;
    }

    private void originalToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        testToolStripMenuItem.Checked = !originalToolStripMenuItem.Checked;

    }
```

Is there any more elegant ways to achieve that?

Comment: Is there only 2 DBs available or are you planning to add more?

Comment: I'm interested in 2 DBs with expand possibility.

Comment: But why I can't make checked at runtime? Shouldn't it work without any coding? Must I set any property in menu item that enables it to be checkable?

Comment: what do you mean by *make checked at runtime* ? Do you mean by default it's checked?

Comment: To enable an item to be checkable, you can set [CheckOnClick to true](https://i.imgsafe.org/a2/a2147e2a6a.png) in designer

Comment: CheckOnClick is set to true now, but still no checking/unchecking

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on this [article](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/make-toolstrip-buttons-act-like-radio-buttons-in-c/) written by Rod Stephens

If you aren't planning to add more DBs to your menu, there is no problem doing it that way.

If you plan to add X BDs to your menu, you can store every menu elements in a `List<ToolStripMenuItem>` and use this list to dynamically check/uncheck elements.

In example, I designed this superb form :

[image]

I **did not set using the designer** any event to those items (named properly : `test1ToolStripMenuItem` to `test4ToolStripMenuItem`)

In the form class, I stored the list of the menu elements in a list called `DBs` and I added the same method to the click event :

```
private List<ToolStripMenuItem> DBs;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DBs = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>
    {
        test1ToolStripMenuItem,
        test2ToolStripMenuItem,
        test3ToolStripMenuItem,
        test4ToolStripMenuItem
    };

    foreach (var DB in DBs)
    {
        DB.Click += FakeRadioBehaviour;
    }
}
```

The method `FakeRadioBehaviour` will iterate through the list of MenuItem, check the `object sender` which correspond to a specific element of the list and uncheck the other ones :

```
private void FakeRadioBehaviour(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var DB in DBs)
    {
        //Checks the sender, unchecks all others ones.
        DB.Checked = ((sender as ToolStripMenuItem) == DB);
    }
}
```